# Crack this rhyme

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> *You can see me inside bars*
>   *and also inside the stars.*
>   *Some may call me a key,*
>   *The above line is a clue to thee!*
>   *My brothers are bigger than me,*
>   *I again say, the above line is a clue to thee!*
>   *I'm found inside a pack,*
>   *Go ahead and try to crack!*

Who am I?

Comment: By any chance are you found at both ends of Alaska?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are a

> Nut - More specifically for most clues, a Peanut.

You can see me inside bars

> Candy Bars or Pub-type bars(bowl of nuts/peanuts)

and also inside the stars.

> oblate-spheriod stars (peanut stars)

Some may call me a key,

> a nut on the end of a bolt, is sometimes referred to as a key.

The above line is a clue to thee!

> rhyme time - (didn't see anything there)

My brothers are bigger than me,

> sounds like a peanut, since a pea is very small and calling children "peanut."

I again say, the above line is a clue to thee!

> rhyme time - (didn't see anything there)

I'm found inside a pack,

> a pack of nuts or peanuts

Go ahead and try to crack!

> a hard nut to crack - or cracking open a peanut shell to get to the nut.

Comment: Could you explain each line? Your answer is correct!

Comment: Sorry. I just signed up and was unfamiliar with the formatting of the site. I think I figured out how to do it.  I will do better in the future to give complete explanations for my answers.

Comment: Cheers! Welcome to PSE...

Comment: Congrats! I was so close... I thought a "key" was the tool which fits the nut and not the nut itself?

Comment: Thanks, @Wolff. I agree. You were right there.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are a:

> **Key** (on the keyboard)

*You can see me inside bars*

> Space*bar*

*and also inside the stars.*

> Asterisk, or *star* key (*)

*Some may call me a key,*
*The above line is a clue to thee!*

> Literally, a key

*My brothers are bigger than me,*
*I again say, the above line is a clue to thee!*

> Most keys (alphanumeric) are smaller than some others (usually meta keys, spacebar, enter, etc.)

*I'm found inside a pack,*

> Many keys are packed together in a keyboard

*Go ahead and try to crack!*

> I tried ☆

Comment: Nice! But, sorry it's not the intended answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are (Note: I didn't read the comments to other answers):

> G (in music and astronomy)

You can see me inside bars

> Musical notes (including G)

and also inside the stars.

> G is a stellar spectral class

Some may call me a key,
The above line is a clue to thee!

> Either (musical) key of G, or a G clef (the word "clef" literally means *key*; clefs are called keys in some languages)

My brothers are bigger than me,
I again say, the above line is a clue to thee!

> The stars of the most other spectral classes (except K and M) are bigger than G-class ones.

I'm found inside a pack,
Go ahead and try to crack!

> Some musical scales (e.g. C major) contain G.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are:

> **Iron**

*You can see me inside bars*

> Iron bars

*and also inside the stars.*

> Iron is the heaviest element produced by stars. Anything heavier is produced by supernovas.

*Some may call me a key,*
*The above line is a clue to thee!*

> An iron key

*My brothers are bigger than me,*
*I again say, the above line is a clue to thee!*

> Not sure about this one. May it's a reference to heavier chemical elements. Or to the Iron Brothers supplement which helps you become *big* at the gym.

*I'm found inside a pack,*

> Iron pack is a nutrient supplement.

*Go ahead and try to crack!*

> Cracking an iron nut (hardware) is a tough one :)

Answer (score 3):

The first two lines make me think

> plasma

because it is in

> bars (as in taverns) in the form of plasma televisions, at least in name.

and it is in

> stars literally as a state of matter.

Not entirely sure of the other lines yet. Is it

> plasma?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are:

> A **kernel**.

*You can see me inside bars*

> A muesli bar is filled with kernels.

*and also inside the stars.*

> In the center of a star there is a kernel (core).

*Some may call me a key,*
*The above line is a clue to thee!*

> The essential part of an idea can be called the kernel (**key**note).

*My brothers are bigger than me,*
*I again say, the above line is a clue to thee!*

> I'm unsure about this one. Maybe it just refers to the kernel being smaller than the fruit or nut it lies within. Also a kernel is used as a reference to something very small.

*I'm found inside a pack,*

> A kernel is often found within a fruit or nut.

*Go ahead and try to crack!*

> A nut can be cracked open to reveal the kernel within.

Comment: almost there !!!

Comment: @Ak19, because i almost got the word right or because I almost explained every line?

Comment: with the 'bars' and 'nut' parts ...